# How to make checkbox visible only after the first checkbox is checked

Tags: android, checkbox, switch-statement, visibility

Am still a learner in android, please am trying to do the following in android. I want my checkbox to show my other checkbox only after I have click the first checkbox, but if the first is unchecked the rest should be invisible. For example Class 1: checkbox, should only show Class 2:checkbox only when Class 1: checked has been selected and so on for the rest checkbox. Please find my code below. Am willing to accept answer immediately once it works

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

    switch (buttonView.getId()) {
        case R.id.chk_clas1:
            //do stuff
            if (chk_clas1.isChecked()) {
                if(c1.equals("0")){adddate(txt_clas1);}
                clas="1";
                fdate=txt_clas1.getText().toString();



            } else {
                txt_clas1.setText("");


            }
            break;
        case R.id.chk_clas2:
            //do stuff

            if (chk_clas2.isChecked()) {
                if(c2.equals("0")) {adddate(txt_clas2);}
                clas="2";
                fdate=txt_clas2.getText().toString();

            } else {
                txt_clas2.setText("");

            }

            break;
        case R.id.chk_clas3:
            //do stuff
            if (chk_clas3.isChecked()) {
                if(c3.equals("0")){
                adddate(txt_clas3);}
                clas="3";
                fdate=txt_clas3.getText().toString();
            } else {
                txt_clas3.setText("");

            }

            break;
        case R.id.chk_clas4:
            //do stuff
            if (chk_clas4.isChecked()) {
                if(c4.equals("0")){
                adddate(txt_clas4);}
                clas="4";
                fdate=txt_clas4.getText().toString();
            } else {
                txt_clas4.setText("");

            }

            break;
        case R.id.chk_clas5:
            //do stuff
            if (chk_clas5.isChecked()) {
                if(c5.equals("0")){
                adddate(txt_clas5);}
                clas="5";
                fdate=txt_clas5.getText().toString();
            } else {
                txt_clas5.setText("");

            }

            break;
        case R.id.chk_clas6:
            //do stuff
            if (chk_clas6.isChecked()) {
                if(c6.equals("0")){
                adddate(txt_clas6);}
                clas="6";
                fdate=txt_clas6.getText().toString();
            } else {
                txt_clas6.setText("");

            }

            break;

        case R.id.chk_service1:
            //do stuff
            if (chk_service1.isChecked()) {
                if(s1.equals("0")){
                adddate(txt_service1);}
                sday="1";
                sdate=txt_service1.getText().toString();
            } else {
                txt_service1.setText("");
            }

            break;

        case R.id.chk_service2:
            //do stuff
            if (chk_service2.isChecked()) {
                if(s2.equals("0")){
                adddate(txt_service2);}
                sday="2";
                sdate=txt_service2.getText().toString();
            } else {
                txt_service2.setText("");
            }

            break;

        case R.id.chk_service3:
            //do stuff
            if (chk_service3.isChecked()) {
                if(s3.equals("0")){
                adddate(txt_service3);}
                sday="3";
                sdate=txt_service3.getText().toString();
            } else {
                txt_service3.setText("");
            }

            break;

        case R.id.chk_service4:
            //do stuff
            if (chk_service4.isChecked()) {
                if(s4.equals("0")){
                adddate(txt_service4);}
                sday="4";
                sdate=txt_service4.getText().toString();
            } else {
                txt_service4.setText("");
            }

            break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not code, just an idea ..
Something out of my head:

```
//Initially
chkBx2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

onCheckListener-> //just showing idea, not code

if(chkbx1.isChecked()){
     chkBx2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
}
```

Comment: thank you for the wonderful idea but were would you suggest I put that Initial code chkBx2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); in my code

Comment: @user3367817 inside the method called `onCreate` of course !

Comment: shouldn't it be invisible in the start . It should become visible after you click it!

Comment: it's okay @user3367817 , mistakes happen with anyone. After we all are humans.